# WhatsApp haven't restored all the media files

Tags: iphone, ios, whatsapp.app

I upgraded from iPhone SE to iPhone XS and restored the WhatsApp backup from iPhone SE to the new iPhone XS.

However, while some media files were imported, not all of them were imported correctly. They are blank.

Example:

[image]

How can I fix this? I'm using the latest version of iOS and WhatsApp on both phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by importing all the old iPhone data to the new iPhone.

This seems to be a better solution than manually moving WhatsApp.